# Broadband connection goes down and shows PPPoE dialup failed. What to do?

Tags: pppoe, dial-up, optical-network-terminal

I have a optical internet connection at my home. Sometimes the connection gets interrupted. When check with the diagnose option in the router config page, it shows 'PPPoE dialup failed'. Why is that? Is the problem at my end or at the ISP end?

Answer (score 1):

Hooking a Fiber connection to a home router requires special connection and attention to detail and procedure. You would not be involved in this except to click on Connect, so ask your ISP.

That is what I would do in your case.